# How to put ü in NSString

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsxmlparser

I receive XML like this:

```
NSString *xml = [[NSString alloc]
                        initWithBytes: [webData mutableBytes]
                        length:[webData length]
                        encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

One node contain `ü` character. And it's value is in `xml` variable and it's fine.
But when I parse `xml` in

```
- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
```

this character is not in string variable.
So if I have `testüsome` in `string` is stored only `test`.

Comment: Does the document have an encoding set in its xml header?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> The xml that I receive is fine. Problem is just when parsing in foundCharacters function.

Comment: Could you show how you initialize the NSXMLParser with the xml string?